# Cannot use Math template in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

First of all, I just want to thanks the people of TeXnicCenter... great application...

I am trying to use the math template in TeXnicCenter, When I compile it, it says missing `\begin{document}`. After googling, I realised that the enconding is the problem. The recommendation is to change the BOM. I cannot find this option in the editor, the question is how to make this work again.

The extange thing is that it fails only using the template. If I type my own code, there is not problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess we need to see the template that triggers the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess you use Windows? I think the problem is that you use UTF-8 with BOM because you are under MS Windows.

Try the following. Open the file you want to compile in TeXnicCenter then go to File->Save As. In the following Save-Dialog at the bottom you will find a drop down menu with the encoding for the file. Select UTF-8 (without the BOM).

Then try to compile it. BTW, which encoding did you use when you write your own files?

Comment: Hmm, for me saving without BOM is the default … Your answer still useful, though!